# How to resize PIL.Image to the closest multiples of 3

Tags: python, algorithm, math

Say I have an image (100, 100). I want to resize it to the closest multiple of 3. In this case I want to resize it to (99, 99).

Is there a good way to code this algorithm?

Comment: The image object has a `.resize()` method which will do this. However, for the sake of making a small change to your image size, you might want to consider whether it's worth the potential impact of quality of doing this - would it be better to just slightly crop the image instead?

Comment: Is your question how to resize an image, or how to get to the closest multiple of 3?

Comment: Closest multiple, @physicalattraction

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should first divide the input number by 3, then round it, and then multiply it by 3 again. This function should do the trick for you.

```
def closest_multiple(original: int, multiple_of: int) -> int:
    """
    Return the closest multiple of `multiple_of` to `original`.
    
    >>> closest_multiple(9, 3)
    9
    >>> closest_multiple(10, 3)
    9
    >>> closest_multiple(11, 3)
    12
    """
    
    return int(round(original / multiple_of)) * multiple_of
```